# Teams Bot Framework Suggested Actions

Tags: python, asynchronous, botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot

I have the following code, written in Python and Bot Framework v4 SDK. How do I make the bot produce buttons with suggested actions, whenever i type "test", using suggestedActions?

I was able to reproduce the run from the sample: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/08.suggested-actions

But it doesn't work when i try to port it over to my bot, sample code below. I the error might be due to my misunderstanding on how async works?

```
class MyBot(ActivityHandler):
    async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):

    [code truncated]
            elif re.search('TEST', str(turn_context.activity.text).upper()):
                      
            print('test...')
            return await self._send_suggested_actions(turn_context)   
   [code truncated]

     async def _send_suggested_actions(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
        reply = MessageFactory.suggested_actions(
        SuggestedActions(
            actions=[
                CardAction(title="Help", type=ActionTypes.im_back, value="help"),
                CardAction(title="Plant", type=ActionTypes.im_back, value="menu"),
            ],
        )
    )
        await turn_context.send_activity(reply)
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised that Suggested Actions do not work in Teams desktop app. It only works in Teams mobile app, and webchat. Disappointing :(

Comment: If it is working in Teams mobile app then definitely it will work in the Teams desktop app as well. I think recent ms team changes impact carousel card numbering, Action toggle, etc. You can create a GitHub issue in the ms team -> https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/7626

Comment: This link indicates Suggested Actions are supposed to work in MS Teams: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/conversation-messages?tabs=dotnet1%2Cdotnet2%2Cdotnet3%2Cdotnet4%2Cdotnet5%2Cdotnet#send-suggested-actions

However, this link indicates it does not work in MS Teams: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channels-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Comment: In both documents clearly mentioned it supports this feature - I think you have confused this line "maximum number of suggested actions in ms team" and it showing as "None". Probably it means there are no exact max numbers but card actions are 3. Because your first link has the screenshot details with 3 suggested actions.

Comment: We are also able to repro the issue using Python sample. We have raised bug for the same.
Could you please try with the below node JS/c# sample. It is working fine.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-suggested-actions

Comment: Thanks. I can’t install nodeJS yet at my work laptop due to restrictions. Will have to wait for the bug to be fixed. Is there a place I can track the resolution of this issue? Thanks again.

Comment: No, you did not have access to Track the bug. We have raised it internally; we will let you know once we get any update.